# Nginx Keep using RAM, same usage at peak and off peak time

Tags: nginx

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 (64 bit), Nginx 1.17.4, Php7.3 VPS and uses the FastCGI cache with PageSpeed module (1GB total RAM). In this VPS, hosted three WordPress sites and they are regional basis. Therefore, those sites have traffic at a certain period of time.

As per the Monit statisitics, this server Nginx uses 31% of RAM at peak time. The problem is that, when there's no visitors to my sites, still nginx uses 31% of the RAM (305.1 MB). If I reboot the VPS at off peak time, then again nginx uses less than 10% RAM until the peak time. After that, it continually uses peak time RAM usage all the time. Although, php7.3-fpm release the RAM usage if there's no any traffic.

Why is that Nginx keep using RAM even at off peak times and not release the RAM if there's no any visitors?

Comment: I suspect that's just the RAM Nginx needs. That's not a lot of RAM, although Monit says my Nginx instance is using 13MB of RAM so it's a lot more than I'm using. I wonder if yours has a lot of cache configured, and the cache may be configured to keep content for 24 hours or more?

Comment: Thank you @Tim , your reply. Actually nginx using over 300MB, not 13MB. Yes, I use FastGCI with 30 days cache life. The problem is that, if there's no any visitors, why Nginx use 30% RAM?

Comment: Probably cache. Turn the cache off or reduce the cache lifetime to 1h and see if RAM usage drops. 13MB is my Nginx RAM usage, I don't know if it has in-memory caching configured - I rely on the OS cache.

Comment: You likely have a memory leak. If you use PageSpeed module, take into account that it has performance impact of its own. If you can get away with manual optimizations (as in, minify/compress assets after deployment), that is often a better choice than having PageSpeed continiously issue `stat` calls even just to check if an asset was changed and need re-optimization (already a performance hit from that).

Comment: I managed to fix it by reducing worker_connection to 2048. Thank you @Tim & @ Danila Vershinin.